# How to Find the Minimum Value in the Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, data-structures, find, binary-search-tree

How can I find the minimum node in this binary search tree. I can't make it work.

....................................................................
....................................................................

```
class BinarySearchTree:

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

    def insert(self, node):
        if node == self.root:  
            return
        elif node < self.root:  
            if self.left:
                self.left.insert(node)
            else:
                self.left = BinarySearchTree(node)
        else: 
            if self.right:
                self.right.insert(node)
            else:
                self.right = BinarySearchTree(node)


    def search(self, target):
        if target == self.root:
            return True
        else:
            if target < self.root:
                if self.left:
                    return self.left.search(target)
                return False

            if target > self.root:
                if self.right:
                    return self.right.search(target)
                return False

    
    def find_min(self, root):
        # traverse left subtree
        while root is not None:
            root = self.left
        return root
```

Comment: [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 1):

```
def find_min(self):
    # traverse left subtree
    current = self
    while self.left is not None:
        current = self.left
    return current.root
```

tree = BinarySearchTree("10")

tree.insert("20")

tree.insert("30")

print(tree.search("20"))  # output: True

print(tree.search("40"))  # output: False

print(tree.find_min())  # output: 10